# Android decentralized P2P network using Tomp2p over Internet without user interaction

Tags: android, networking, distributed, p2p

I am working on a android project to create decentralized network of peers to send/receive file through internet without user interaction using Tomp2p. Is it possible or is there better way to do this job?